# Preparing macro content in a loop (calling \foreach from \edef)

Tags: expansion, loops, foreach

I need to do something like `\def\MyArray{{1, 2, 3, 4}}` but with a dynamical number of elements.

The following command makes the string:

`\newcommand{\MakeArray}[1]{\{ 1 \foreach \x in {2, ..., #1}{ , \x} \}}`

How can I put the expanded result in a macro? I tried doing `\edef\MyArray{\MakeArray{4}}` but it doesn't compile...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
\def\MakeArray#1#2{% #1: macro that expands to the list, #2: final number
  \toks@={1}\@tempcnta=\@ne
  \loop\ifnum\@tempcnta<#2\relax
    \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
    \toks@=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\toks@\expandafter,\number\@tempcnta}%
  \repeat
  \edef#1{{\the\toks@}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\MakeArray\MyArray{4}

\texttt{\meaning\MyArray} % should print macro:->{1,2,3,4}

\end{document}
```

Doing this with `\foreach` is (almost) impossible, because `\edef` doesn't perform assignments, only expansion, and `\foreach` does tens of assignments to work. You can see from the code that the `\edef` I do is just the last thing of the ">1" case (there's no check that the input is sensible, so be careful to say something like `\MakeArray\MyArray{x}` that would die horribly.

The idea is simple: I put `1` in the token register `\toks@` and then loop until the scratch counter `\@tempcnta` reaches the value `#2`, augmenting the tokens in `\toks@`.

The curious line

```
\toks@=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\toks@\expandafter,\number\@tempcnta}
```

deserves an explanation. After `\toks@=` TeX wants to see an open brace (after expansion), so it expands the following token, which is `\expandafter`; good, this expands after the open brace and the token it finds is `\the`. Well, `\the` needs to see some specific kinds of (unexpandable) tokens after it, so it expands in order to see what really comes along; the `\expandafter` expands the following `\expandafter` which finally expands `\number`! Now `\the` performs its duty, in this case to "free" the contents of `\toks@`. So, if `\@tempcnta=2`, TeX is presented with

```
\toks@={1,2}
```

exactly what we needed.

---

A different method, which is much more easily customizable, is using `expl3`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\MakeArray}{ m m }
 {% #1: macro that expands to the list, #2: final number
  \jeremie_make_array:n { #2 }
  \tl_set_eq:NN #1 \l__jeremie_array_temp_tl
 }

\tl_new:N \l__jeremie_array_temp_tl
\seq_new:N \l__jeremie_array_temp_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \jeremie_make_array:n #1
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__jeremie_array_temp_seq
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__jeremie_array_temp_seq { ##1 }
   }
  \tl_set:Nx \l__jeremie_array_temp_tl { \seq_use:Nn \l__jeremie_array_temp_seq { , } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\MakeArray\MyArray{4}

\texttt{\meaning\MyArray} % should print macro:->{1,2,3,4}

\MakeArray\MyArray{1}

\texttt{\meaning\MyArray} % should print macro:->{1}

\MakeArray\MyArray{0}

\texttt{\meaning\MyArray} % should print macro:->

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! and for the explanation too. Is the special case for `1` for performance reasons?

Comment: I didn't even try without the special case. Does it work?

Comment: It works fine. Do you want me to edit your answer to remove the special case?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative to egreg's answer.  It is a slavish imitation of the algorithm, but instead of using token registers and `\loop` I use `\foreach` and `\edef`.  It's probably quite a bit slower, as a result, but (since it uses PGF and `etoolbox`) less intimidating.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,etoolbox}

% #1 = list macro, #2 = length
\newcommand\MakeArray[2]{%
 \ifnumless{#2}{1}
  {\def#1{}}
  {\def#1{1}%
   \ifnumgreater{#2}{1}
   {%
    \foreach \n in {2,...,#2} {%
     \xdef#1{#1,\n}%
    }%
    \xdef#1{{#1}}%
   }{}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}

Pre-text\MakeArray\MyArray{4}post-text

\texttt{\meaning\MyArray} % should print macro:->{1,2,3,4}

\MakeArray\MyArray{1}\texttt{\meaning\MyArray}

\MakeArray\MyArray{0}\texttt{\meaning\MyArray}

\MakeArray\MyArray{-1}\texttt{\meaning\MyArray}

\end{document}
```

I put in the pre-text and post-text line just to verify that, indeed, my macro does not produce unwanted spaces. I also cover the special cases when `#2 = 1` or `#2 < 0`, which it looks like egreg was asked to remove (???).

This answer is part of [my "campaign"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33154/how-to-write-readable-commands/33169#33169) to remind people that any question that is more about programming than about TeX can be answered using PGF.  Actually, that campaign is about `pgfkeys` in particular, so let me give a key-based answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,pgfkeys,etoolbox}

\pgfkeys{
 /make array/.is family, /make array,
 accumulate/.code = {%
  \ifnumgreater{#1}{1}
   {\pgfkeysalso{array/.append = {,#1}}}
   {}%
 },
 initialize/.code = {%
  \ifnumgreater{#1}{0}
   {\pgfkeysalso{array/.initial = 1}}
   {\pgfkeysalso{array/.initial = {}}}%
 },
 do/.style 2 args = {
  initialize = #2,
  accumulate/.list = {1,...,#2},
  array/.get = #1
 }
}

\newcommand\MakeArray[2]{\pgfkeys{/make array, do = #1{#2}}}

\begin{document}

Pre-text\MakeArray\MyArray{4}post-text

\texttt{\meaning\MyArray} % should print macro:->{1,2,3,4}

\MakeArray\MyArray{1}\texttt{\meaning\MyArray}

\MakeArray\MyArray{0}\texttt{\meaning\MyArray}

\MakeArray\MyArray{-1}\texttt{\meaning\MyArray}

\end{document}
```

This works like this:

- The `\MakeArray` macro just calls `\pgfkeys` with the appropriate key and value, and it handles everything.
- The key `/make array/do` just calls a few other keys; it's basically a dispatch function.  The names should be self-explanatory.  Since `pgfkeys` has the capability to put key contents into macros, I let it define `\MyArray` using the `.get` handler on the `array` key.
- The `initialize` and `accumulate` keys each handle one of the special-cases tests that I had before.  `etoolbox` is still necessary for readable conditional statements, but now they are meaningfully associated with named subroutines.
- The way `accumulate/.list` works is that it calls `accumulate` on each element of the list.  The test in `accumulate` decides whether a number is worth adding; if `#2 <= 1`, then it's not.  The `initialize` key has already decided whether 1 is in the list, and otherwise, negative numbers should never be included.

Comment: Nice. I wouldn't use `\edef#1`: alternating local and global assignments for the same variable can lead to "save stack build-up"; so `\xdef#1` is better. Actually yours seems slightly faster.

Comment: @egreg: I would not have expected that (re:faster).  Thanks for the tip about save stack buildup; I never think about that, but perhaps I should (is this the next step in TeXpertise?).

Comment: If I call your macro with 10000, I get 108 save stack words used; with `\xdef` it drops down to 50; with mine it's 36. Not a big problem, it seems: but a complex document might exhaust the available memory.

Comment: Using `\xdef` in my macros is slightly faster indeed (your and my methods give similar results).

Comment: @egreg: That's a pretty significant waste of save stack space, indeed.  I was just surprised that a high-level, complex construction like `\foreach` could be faster than something made entirely from TeX primitives (well, `\loop` is a pretty trivial macro).  And I'd thought that token registers were supposed to be faster than macro expansions.