# Strip control characters from token

Tags: strings

I've added a hook to lstlisting to do some special highlighting. Now I've got it to highlight %-prefixed variables just fine, but I'd like to handle the special case "%this" in another way.

Unfortunately when lstlisting find a keyword followed by a comma, it gives me `this\unhbox \voidb@x \kern \z@` which I have a hard time parsing.. Essentially I just need to check if it is a "this" keyword, this has proved tricky however.

Just to be a little more specific, I can't just do a substring because %thisVal should not be accepted, only %this.

I tried [the Sanitizer from another thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34029/can-one-define-an-expandable-command-that-removes-control-sequences-from-its-arg) but had no success.

If the token didn't have all that other stuff appended, all I needed to do is:

```
    \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\@restTestChar}{this}=0%
    \def\lst@thestyle{\color{thisColor}}%
    \else
    \def\lst@thestyle{\color{variableColor}}%
    \fi
```

I was thinking that any way to just remove anything after the first \ should work, but I can't figure out how to do this as it is not a string per se.

Edit: To give a little more context, I'm trying to make an extension to a lstlisting-based SyntaxHighlighlighter such that %this is highlighted in red and not the same color that other %-prefixed variables are highlighted in. I have a [working sample](https://www.writelatex.com/1929188swykrx#/4853973/) that shows the issue. The lst-hook just checks whether the token is "%this" and doesn't handle the case where it is `%this\unhbox \voidb@x \kern \z@` which is what lst gives me for some reason. I need to handle both cases.

Comment: Some more context is needed.

Comment: The addition is useless, sorry.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why? I'm not sure what you need, theres a full working sample and a precise description on what goes wrong?

It is this comparison `\ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\@restTestChar}{this}=0%` that I need to change such that it takes into account the case where `%this` isfollowed by the 4 control sequences as described in the question.