# Command behavior depending on current environment

Tags: macros, environments, conditionals

I would like to write a LaTeX macro whose code depends on the parent environment such as:

```
\newcommand\test{
%if current_environment=env1
test1
%elseif current_environment=env2
test2
%else
}

\begin{env1}
\test %output test1
\end{env1}


\begin{env2}
\test %output test2
\end{env2}

\test %output nothing
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The current name of the environment is saved in the macro `\@currenvir`.

In the example below is defined a new test named `\ifenv`. The syntax of the command is:

```
\ifenv{environment name}{TRUE}{FALSE}
```

`\ifenv` test whether the name of the current environment is equal to the input or not. Depending of the result the true or false part will be used.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\ifenv#1{
   \def\@tempa{#1}%
   \ifx\@tempa\@currenvir
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
   \fi
}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{enva}{}{}
\newenvironment{envb}{}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{enva}
\ifenv{enva}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\ifenv{envb}{TRUE}{FALSE}
\end{enva}

\begin{envb}
\ifenv{enva}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\ifenv{envb}{TRUE}{FALSE}
\end{envb}
\end{document}
```

It is important to use `\begin` --- `\end` to define `\@currenvir`.

As Marc van Dongen mentioned the test fails if you combine environments.

In this case I would use another solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\Mycurrentvir{document}
\def\ifenv#1{
   \def\@tempa{#1}%
   \ifx\@tempa\Mycurrentvir
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
   \fi
}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{enva}{\def\Mycurrentvir{enva}}{}
\newenvironment{envb}{\def\Mycurrentvir{envb}}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{enva}
\ifenv{enva}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\ifenv{envb}{TRUE}{FALSE}
\end{enva}

\begin{envb}
\ifenv{enva}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\ifenv{envb}{TRUE}{FALSE}
\end{envb}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Examples of usage?

Comment: @egreg: Example ;-)

Comment: This is a partial solution. For example, if there's another environment ``in between'' it gives the wrong result. For example, `\begin{enva} \begin{tt} \ifenv{enva}{THIS IS RIGHT}{I AM WRONG}\end{tt}\end{enva}`.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Of course. `begin{..}` defines the `\@currenvir`. In other cases you must work with flags ala `\newif\ifenva` and set the flags at the beginning of the environment.

Comment: @Marco It would be nice if it was possible to modify the solution and cater for cases like this. For example, the `center` environment is something that users may typically want to use as an ``inbetween'' environment.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: I edited my post.

Comment: @Marco Thanks. I think the new solution is better.

Answer (score 6):

A more easily customizable version can be obtained with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{}
  {
   \prg_case_str:onn { \@currenvir }
      {
       {envA}{\testenvA}
       {envB}{\testenvB}
      }
      {\testDefault}
  }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newenvironment{envA}{}{}
\newenvironment{envB}{}{}
\newcommand{\testenvA}{We're~in~\texttt{envA}}
\newcommand{\testenvB}{We're~in~\texttt{envB}}
\newcommand{\testDefault}{We're~neither~in~\texttt{envA}~nor~in~\texttt{envB}}

\begin{document}

\test

\begin{envA}\test\end{envA}

\begin{envB}\test\end{envB}

\end{document}
```

Of course, these definition don't take into account nested environments: so

```
\begin{envA}\begin{envC}\test\end{envC}\end{envA}
```

will produce `\testDefault` and *not* `\testenvA`.

A different approach is to add code to the environments:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\testenvA}{We're~in~\texttt{envA}}
\newcommand{\testenvB}{We're~in~\texttt{envB}}
\newcommand{\testDefault}{We're~neither~in~\texttt{envA}~nor~in~\texttt{envB}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{envA}{\renewcommand{\test}{\testenvA}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{envB}{\renewcommand{\test}{\testenvB}}
\newcommand{\test}{\testDefault} % default
```

In this case

```
\begin{envA}\begin{envC}\test\end{envC}\end{envA}
```

will produce `\testenvA`.

Comment: The same problem which Marc mentioned. Is there a LaTeX 3 solution?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel The definition of `\test` must go in the environment's definition, then.

Comment: I thought there is a command like `previousenv` or so ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel How many steps above?

Comment: I think 3 is enough.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Not without LaTeX maintaining a stack of the open environments, which it currently doesn't. I guess it's a good idea for LaTeX3, that I hope will also add hooks for the `\begin` and `\end` part (like what's provided by `etoolbox`).

Comment: @egreg Can you add a more updated version for `expl3` please :D

Answer (score 6):

No need to use any conditionals at all: let TeX do the switching for you!  Here's how it works:

- For every environment for which you want a special effect, call `\NewEnvCode{<environment>}{<code>}`.  You should at least write `\NewEnvCode{document}{<code>}`; this is installed as the default action for unspecified environments (including top-level; i.e. inside the `document` "environment").
- Call `\RunEnvCode` anywhere.  If it's in one of your special environments, then your code will be run; otherwise, the default code is run.  You can make the current environment the default for all sub-environments by calling `\MakeDefault` (this is how `document` is installed, actually).  This is reset after you leave the calling environment.

Here's my code with a sample document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% Simulated package file
\begin{filecontents}{envcode.sty}
\newcommand\NewEnvCode[2]{%
 \expandafter\def\csname code@#1\endcsname{#2}%
 \expandafter\def\csname change@code@#1\endcsname{%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\Code\csname code@#1\endcsname
 }%
}

\newcommand\MakeDefault{%
 \expandafter\let\expandafter\code@@default\csname code@\@currenvir\endcsname
}

\newcommand\RunEnvCode{%
 \let\Code=\code@@default
 \csname change@code@\@currenvir\endcsname
 \Code
}

\AtBeginDocument{\MakeDefault}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{envcode}

\NewEnvCode{document}{default code}
\NewEnvCode{equation}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2} dx = \sqrt{2\pi}}
\NewEnvCode{itemize}{itemize!}

\begin{document}
 \RunEnvCode

 \begin{equation}
  \RunEnvCode
 \end{equation}

 \begin{enumerate}
  \item \RunEnvCode
 \end{enumerate}

 \begin{itemize}
  \item \RunEnvCode

  \item
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item \RunEnvCode
  \end{enumerate}

  \item \MakeDefault
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item \RunEnvCode
  \end{enumerate}
 \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Okay, here's how it really works:

- `\NewEnvCode` creates a macro `\change@code@#1`, where `#1` is the name of an environment, and which, when called, redefines something called `\Code` to produce the code `#2`.  Actually, it creates a macro `\code@#1` that produces `#2` and then has `\change@code@#1` `\let` `\Code` to this macro.
- `\RunEnvCode` begins by giving `\Code` the default effect `\code@@default`, and then tries to call one of the `\change@code@<env>` macros, with `<env> = \@currenvir` as described in the other answers (the name of the current environment).  It constructs this macro name using `\csname...\endcsname`.
- Because of the way `\csname` works, if the control sequence it produces is not already defined, it acts like `\relax`; i.e. does nothing.  So if the current environment is not one of the ones you specified, `\Code` remains defined as the default action, and otherwise, gets switched.
- `\MakeDefault` just `\let`s the default action `\code@@default` to `\code@<env>`, so that if `\RunEnvCode` is called in an unknown environment, it *thinks* it's calling the default, but that default will be whatever was last set by `\MakeDefault`.

If you want to add more cases, just call `\NewEnvCode` for the relevant environments.

Answer (score 3):

I've created two "dummy" environments `envA` and `envB` to illustrate the use of `\@currenvir`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{envA}{}{\par}% Dummy environment
\newenvironment{envB}{}{\par}% Dummy environment
\makeatletter
\newcommand\test{%
  \def\@tempa{envA}% if current_environment=envA
  \ifx\@tempa\@currenvir test1\else%
  \def\@tempa{envB}% if current_environment=envB
  \ifx\@tempa\@currenvir test2\else\fi\fi%
}
\begin{document}

Entering \texttt{envA} \par
\begin{envA}
\test %output test1
\end{envA}
Exiting \texttt{envA}

Entering \texttt{envB} \par
\begin{envB}
\test %output test2
\end{envB}
Exiting \texttt{envB}

No environment \par
\test %output nothing
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since I believe you should [use `pgfkeys` for everything](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33154/how-to-write-readable-commands/33169#33169) (programming-related) let me submit a second answer with the same general behavior as the first.  The only difference in the interface is that `\NewEnvCode` takes just one argument, which is a comma-separated list of key-value pairs `<env> = <code>` (put `<code>` in braces if it has commas or equals signs).  The difference in coding is readily apparent:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% Simulated package file
\begin{filecontents}{pgfkeys-envcode.sty}
\RequirePackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{
 /envcode/.is family, /envcode,
 define/.is family,
 code/.is family,
}

\pgfkeys{
 /envcode/define,
 .unknown/.style = {
  /envcode/code/\pgfkeyscurrentname/.code={#1},
 },
}

\AtBeginDocument{\MakeDefault}

\newcommand\NewEnvCode[1]{%
 \pgfkeys{/envcode/define,#1}%
}

\newcommand\MakeDefault{%
 \pgfkeys{/envcode/code/.unknown/.style/.expanded=\@currenvir}%
}

\newcommand\RunEnvCode{%
 \pgfkeys{/envcode/code,\@currenvir}%
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{pgfkeys-envcode}

\NewEnvCode{
 document = default code,
 equation = {\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2} dx = \sqrt{2\pi}},
 itemize  = itemize!,
}

\begin{document}
 \RunEnvCode

 \begin{equation}
  \RunEnvCode
 \end{equation}

 \begin{enumerate}
  \item \RunEnvCode
 \end{enumerate}

 \begin{itemize}
  \item \RunEnvCode

  \item
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item \RunEnvCode
  \end{enumerate}

  \item \MakeDefault
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item \RunEnvCode
  \end{enumerate}
 \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Here's how it works:

- Recall that `pgfkeys` has the notion of a "directory tree" of keys, and that its keys can perform quite general functions other than storing values: for example, they can invoke other keys, and there is a mechanism for dealing with unknown keys via a default search path.  This is the mechanism I exploit to get the "default" behavior.
- Any key `<env> = <code>` you pass to `\NewEnvCode` defines a key in the directory `/envcode/code` with the name `<env>`, and sets it to execute `<code>` when run; when you call `\RunEnvCode`, it tries to execute this key with `<env> = \@currenvir`.
- When `/envcode/code/<env>` does not exist, the default "handler" `/envcode/code/.unknown` is called instead.  This is set up by `\MakeDefault`, which says that it should have the "style" `\@currenvir` (completely expanded at "compile" time), meaning that it just calls the key of that name, e.g. "document".  I made it so that `\MakeDefault` is called right after `\begin{document}`, so that with no other changes, the default code is for "document", which you should set up.
- This same mechanism is responsible for the workings of `\NewEnvCode` itself: each key you give it is executed under the directory `/envcode/define`, which *never* has any keys defined in it.  The unknown handler there always runs, and we ask it to set up a key in `/envcode/code` of the same name, whose "code" is `<code>`.  This is a convenience for the user, so you don't have to write `/.code` after everything.

As you can see, the behavior you are looking for is basically equivalent to the lookup behavior of `pgfkeys`, so this is a pretty appropriate tool in addition to being superior programming-wise to the funny things that happen in TeX.  Obviously it's a *lot* more complicated behind the scenes; every one of these macros probably expands to dozens of internal ones before eventually doing effectively what I wrote in my other answer.  However, this code is self-documenting and, because `pgfkeys` is so flexible, much more easily extendable.