# Ensure `description` or `itemize`

Tags: macros, environments

Is there a way to make sure that a macro can only be used inside a specific environment, say `description`?

I am looking for something like the `\ensuremath` macro.

Comment: Please clarify this question. The `\ensuremath` macro switches to math mode to typeset its argument if necessary. If your macro is called outside a `description`, do you want it to flag an error, or start a `description`?

Comment: Rather than make an answer that's only a link, here's a link to something I wrote in response to a similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39755/575

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can modify the definition of the environment in order to set the command to either work or not. For the `description` environment, you could use the following code for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\olddesc\description
\def\myrealcmd#1{\textbf{#1}}
\def\myfakecmd#1{#1}
\let\mycmd\myfakecmd
\def\description{\let\mycmd\myrealcmd\olddesc}
\begin{document}
  \noindent This is a \mycmd{test} outside of description.
  \begin{description}
    \item This is a \mycmd{test} inside of one description.
    \begin{description}
      \item This is a \mycmd{test} inside of two descriptions.
    \end{description}
    \item This is a \mycmd{test} after a nested description.
  \end{description}
  And a \mycmd{test} outside again.
\end{document}
```

With the following result:

[image: Modified description environment]

Comment: Nested description environments will break this, won't they? Because after the end of the inside `description`, the end code will be run…

Comment: @Seamus: You are correct, I added a simple counter to solve this issue.

Comment: @Seamus: I had composed an answer that include this tweak but then saw that it was not necessary.  I had tested both this and egreg's solution, and both just worked fine. I assumed it was due to some sort of grouping effect.  So you can probably put your original simpler solution back (unless I am missing something).

Comment: @PeterGrill: I think the original would not work when you have a first level of description, then one within that and then an item after that. That is, within the first description, but after the second level description has finished. Because then the end of the second level description will have set `\mycmd` to `\fakecmd`.

Comment: @wh1t3: Tried exactly (which is your updated MWE) and the original solution still works.

Comment: @PeterGrill: You are right, hadn't actually tested it. I can't really explain *why* this works though. I think it is due to grouping, like you suggested. Because I can also completely remove the redefinition of `\enddescription` and it still works. I'll remove the edit and change the original code.

Comment: You should use your old code but the new MWE to show that it works for the case of a nested environment with an item for the parent after the end

Answer (score 8):

The `etoolbox` package provides hooks for the environments; so you can define a "hidden" macro and then activate it only in selected environments

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter % protect the definition of \mymacro
\newcommand{\@mymacro}{whatever}
\AtBeginEnvironment{description}{\let\mymacro\@mymacro}
\makeatother

% now we help users
\newcommand{\mymacro}{%
  \PackageError{mypackage}
    {\protect\mymacro\space outside `description'}
    {You can use \protect\mymacro\space only inside `description'}%
}
```

You can add other environments and also provide a different meaning in different environments:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter % protect the definition of \mymacro
\newcommand{\description@mymacro}{whatever}
\AtBeginEnvironment{description}{\let\mymacro\description@mymacro}
\newcommand{\itemize@mymacro}{whatever}
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\let\mymacro\itemize@mymacro}
\makeatother
```

Comment: The output of `\PackageError` needs a space following `\protect\mymacro`. I tried the usual `\ ` and `~` but I guess that is not the correct way to insert space there.

Comment: Yes, one needs `\space` (I always forget). One can use `\noexpand` instead of `\protect`, but the latter is good practice.

Answer (score 6):

The current environment name is stored in `\@currenvir` so you could test that that was `description` or whatever, but nested environments would mask that. If you need your macro to be allowed  *anywhere* in description, even in a nested tabular or itemize, say, then you would need to save `\@currenvir`  into another macro at the start of description (either explicitly or by patching the definition of `\description` then you can test this local macro without it being over-written by nested environments.