# Equation Counters in and outside Theorems

Tags: equations, numbering, theorems

I am trying to setup the counters so that the equations and theorems increment by section and there is no overlap between equation and theorem numbering.  I also would like to be able to number equations inside theorems as a subnumber of the theorem number.

For example in section 2 I might have an equation first that would be labeled (2.1) and then a theorem, labeled 2.2 where there is an equation inside the theorem which I would want labeled 2.2.1.

Comment: What package(s) are you using to generate your theorem(s)?

Answer (score 5):

In the solution below I've used

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}            % (1.1), (1.2), etc
\newtheorem{mytheorem}[equation]{Theorem}   % Theorems share equation numbers
```

to get numbering `(1.1)`, `(1.2)`, etc. and then `mytheorem` gets the same numbers as `equations`.

I've borrowed some important code from [Command behavior depending on current environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39738/command-behavior-depending-on-current-environment) so that my `newcounter` `subequations` can be incremented, but *only* when within `mytheorem`.

I've used the [`etoolbox`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/etoolbox) for its important `\appto` command.

[image: screenshot]

Complete MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}            % (1.1), (1.2), etc
\newtheorem{mytheorem}[equation]{Theorem}   % Theorems share equation numbers

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39738/command-behavior-depending-on-current-environment
\makeatletter
\def\Mycurrentvir{document}
\def\ifenv#1{
   \def\@tempa{#1}%
   \ifx\@tempa\Mycurrentvir
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
   \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{subequation}
\appto\mytheorem{\setcounter{subequation}{0}%
                               \def\Mycurrentvir{mytheorem}%
                               \renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}.\arabic{subequation}}}
                               \AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\ifenv{mytheorem}{\refstepcounter{subequation}\addtocounter{equation}{-1}}{}}



\begin{document}

\section{My section}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:first}
  y=mx+b
\end{equation}
\begin{mytheorem}\label{thm:test}
  \begin{equation}\label{eq:test}
    y=ax^2+bx+c
  \end{equation}
  Another equation
  \begin{equation}
    y=ax^2+bx+c
  \end{equation}
\end{mytheorem}
  \begin{equation}
    y=x^3
  \end{equation}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item First equation: \eqref{eq:first}
    \item Equation within theorem: \eqref{eq:test}
    \item Theorem reference: \ref{thm:test}
  \end{itemize}

\section{another section}
\begin{equation}
  y=mx+b
\end{equation}
\begin{mytheorem}
  \begin{equation}
    y=ax^2+bx+c
  \end{equation}
  Another equation
  \begin{equation}
    y=ax^2+bx+c
  \end{equation}
\end{mytheorem}
  \begin{equation}
    y=x^3
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```