# Blank line occurring between description term and itemize list when using style=nextline

Tags: lists, itemize, enumitem, description

In my Sphinx project, I have description lists that start with either a paragraph or a list. Since I want the description term to be on its own line, I use `enumitem` with `{style=nextline}`. The problem is that this causes an extra line of space to appear after the term if an itemize list follows. Being auto-generated by Sphinx, though, I'm limited to setting options in the preamble to fix it. Does such a fix exist that prevents the extra space?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{style=nextline}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[{This is a term.}] \leavevmode
This is a description of the term, usually spanning multiple lines,
which should start on its own line.
\end{description}

\begin{description}
\item[{This is a term containing an itemize list.}] \leavevmode
\begin{itemize}
\item {} 
This is an item with too much space between it and the term above.
\end{itemize}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

**Update:** To solve the problem at hand I have the Makefile applying karlkoeller's fix across the entire file. However, this post on [changing behaviour depending on environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39738/command-behavior-depending-on-current-environment) helped me come up with this solution that almost works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\ifenv#1{
   \def\@tempa{#1}%
   \ifx\@tempa\@currenvir
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
   \fi
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{style=nextline}
\setlist[itemize]{before=\ifenv{description}{\vspace*{-1.5\baselineskip}}{\ldots}}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[{This is a term.}] \leavevmode
This is a description of the term, usually spanning multiple lines, which should start on its own line.
\end{description}

\begin{description}
\item[{This is a term containing an itemize list.}] \leavevmode
\begin{itemize}
\item {} 
This is an item with too much space between it and the term above.
\end{itemize}
\end{description}

Text in between
\begin{itemize}
\item {} 
This is a bare itemize.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

What's supposed to happen is the code passed to `before` is run wherever an `itemize` list starts to determine if it's inside a `description`, and apply the fix if necessary. However, it's returning the false condition (`\ldots`) each time because the code is being evaluated in the preamble, rather than the document itself. I figure `expandafter` is the answer, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The code is actually being evaluated inside the `itemize`, inside the `description`. At that point, `\@currenvir` is "itemize", so the comparison to "description" is false. You might ask the description environment to record its name and nesting level in some macros, and then itemize can test *those* macros to see if (1) it is inside a description and (2) its own nesting level is one greater than the description's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No better ideas at the moment...

You can add

```
\setlist[itemize]{before=\vspace*{-1.5\baselineskip}}
```

in the preamble.

Beware that this will affect all `itemize` environments...

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{style=nextline}
\setlist[itemize]{before=\vspace*{-1.5\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[{This is a term.}] \leavevmode
This is a description of the term, usually spanning multiple lines,
which should start on its own line.
\end{description}

\begin{description}
\item[{This is a term containing an itemize list.}] \leavevmode
\begin{itemize}
\item {}
This is an item with too much space between it and the term above.
\end{itemize}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Didn't know about before, so that's helpful. Is there any way to conditionally apply a command if, say, the `itemize` comes after `\leavevmode` or is inside a `description`?

Comment: @Eric3 I'm afraid I don't know any way.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it programatically by following Dan's suggestion of having the description set a macro `\indesc` indicating it's active, and having the `itemize` apply the fix if it's true. The itemize then resets `\indesc` globally to prevent the fix from being applied to subsequent lists within the description. The only caveat I can see is if the description text has text appearing before the list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\indesc{FALSE}
\makeatletter
\def\ifdesc{
  \def\@istrue{TRUE}%
  \ifx\indesc\@istrue
    \vspace*{-1.0\baselineskip}
    \gdef\indesc{FALSE}
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{style=nextline,before=\def\indesc{TRUE},after=\def\indesc{FALSE}}
\setlist[enumerate]{before=\ifdesc}
\setlist[itemize]{before=\ifdesc}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[{This is a term.}] \leavevmode
This is a description of the term, usually spanning multiple lines,
which should start on its own line.
\end{description}

\begin{description}
\item[{This is a term containing two itemize lists.}] \leavevmode
\begin{itemize}
\item {}
This is an itemize list with the extra space above removed.
\end{itemize}
Some text in between.
\begin{itemize}
\item {}
This is an itemize list left untouched.
\end{itemize}
\end{description}

Some text after the description.
\begin{itemize}
\item {}
This is another itemize list left untouched.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Accepted your answer because it got me to a fix that worked without potential side effects.