# Normalizing nested environments for cleaner design (LyX)

Tags: lyx, environments, exam, nesting

LyX supports nested environments (e.g., `begin{itemize}...\item...`) intuitively with the Tab key. I'd like to get this to work for questions in a layout with the Exam class.

Exam nests questions with the following itemized-like environments: Questions, Parts, Subparts, Subsubparts. The trouble with this in LyX is that a tab key in LyX recreates (nests) the same environment. A user has to both use the Tab key (to change the nesting level) **and** change the paragraph style (e.g., Question -> Part after a tab press).

Since LyX is set up to nest intuitively if the environment names are the same, I thought of the idea to code only one paragraph style in a layout, such as the `myquestions` environment with an `\item` that is `\myquestion`

LyX can easily create a LaTeX file with:

```
\begin{myquestions}
     \myquestion[4] What is 2 + 2?
     \myquestion Answer each of the following as best you can.
     \begin{myquestions}
         \myquestion[2] What's the meaning of life. 
         \myquestion[2] How old are you. 
     \end{myquestions}
\end{myquestions}
```

The problem I'm having is how do I get the above to convert to what Exam expects. That is:

```
\begin{questions}
     \question[4] What is 2 + 2?
     \question Answer each of the following as best you can.
     \begin{parts}
         \part[2] What's the meaning of life. 
         \part[2] How old are you. 
     \end{parts}
\end{questions}
```

I can manage to re-write the `\myquestion` to the proper `\question` or `\part` item depending on current environment (sort of, because it always seems to be the same, e.g., `myquestions`). It seems that coding this requires knowing what level of nesting one is in. ​[Command behavior depending on current environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39738/17868) seems useful, for example.

The second problem is where I'm totally stumped: how to convert an environment name (`\begin{myquestions}` -> `\begin{questions}` or `\begin{parts}` depending on the nesting level). It's out of my league for coding LaTeX and I didn't find anything on TSE.

---

Edit: thanks to the help here, I've got my [LyX Exam document class layout](https://github.com/fuhrmanator/lyx-layouts) working (and documented).

Comment: Since you describe how to convert your LyX challenge into a LaTeX challenge, I believe that this is a general LaTeX question rather than a LyX-specific question. I hope that LaTeX gurus can help you with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my naive shot:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\newcounter{mydepth}%
\newcommand{\myenvironmentname}{%
\ifnum\value{mydepth}=0notinquestion\fi%
\ifnum\value{mydepth}=1question\fi%
\ifnum\value{mydepth}=2part\fi%
\ifnum\value{mydepth}=3subpart\fi%
\ifnum\value{mydepth}=4subsubpart\fi%
\ifnum\value{mydepth}>4undefinedquestion\fi%
}%
\newcommand{\myquestion}{\csname \myenvironmentname\endcsname}%
\newenvironment{myquestions}%
  {\stepcounter{mydepth}\begin{\myenvironmentname s}}%
  {\end{\myenvironmentname s}\addtocounter{mydepth}{-1}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{myquestions}
     \myquestion[4] What is 2 + 2?
     \myquestion Answer each of the following as best you can.
     \begin{myquestions}
         \myquestion[2] What's the meaning of life.
         \myquestion[2] How old are you.
     \end{myquestions}
\end{myquestions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works wonderfully well when I updated the LyX style in my layout, too. Thank you very much! Many redundant styles disappear. Truly Occam's razor.

Comment: Let's hope it does... there might be corner cases

Comment: I put the layout file and sample exam on GitHub: https://github.com/fuhrmanator/lyx-layouts